# Is it possible to use Try catch block inside a catch block?

Tags: java

I have asked a question in aptitude test that a new try catch block can be inside a catch block or not?
For example

```
try {
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Is this valid in Java?

Comment: Why not write it up and compile/run through it?

Comment: Why should it not be possible?

Comment: by the way, Java is case-sensitive. your example will not compile

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should ask his/her compiler (or IDE)

Comment: Question is unclear. If you are asking just if one could have try inside catch than answer is 'yes'.

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting this question.. I was too much confused that's why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible tried following example with java8. it is working fine.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        try{
            System.out.println("try1");
            throw  new Exception("Exception1");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("catch1");
            try{
                System.out.println("try2");
                throw  new Exception("Exception2");
            }catch(Exception e1){
                System.out.println("catch2");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes (given that you use upper/lower case correctly: **t**ry, **c**atch, **E**xception)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible because if any exception is occurs in try then it's catch and we want to add some logic or next implementation in catch block then we can.for example if we write code for get data in outer try block and getting any exception and we need add some logic like file releated or thread releated then we add and use try catch block in outer catch.